# How to use a index of colum from table find by xpath in other xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have a strog xpath with index of colum write in. But if I had a column betwin two old column, my xpath is broke. In my sample `1` and `4` is index of colum write in

```
//table[@id='users-table']/tbody//tr[td[1][text()='05680']]/td[4][text()='5 street']
```

so I have two second xpath find my columns and I want use in my first xpath.

```
//table[@id="users-table"]/thead/tr/th[text()='Phone']
//table[@id="users-table"]/thead/tr/th[text()='adress']

      +---------------------------------------- -+-------------+
      |  Phone | Name  |  Firstname   | adress   | add button  |
      +------------------------------------------+-------------+
      |  05678 | foo   |  toto        | 4 street | edit button |
      |  05680 | foo2  |  toto2       | 5 street | edit button |
      |  05689 | foo3  |  toto3       | 6 street | edit button |
      |  05690 | foo4  |  toto4       | 7 street | edit button |                                     
      +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

- `add button` have id="add-user-button"

**resume :** I want change `1` by `//table[@id="users-table"]/thead/tr/th[text()='Phone']` and `4` by `//table[@id="users-table"]/thead/tr/th[text()='adress']`

same question for find `add button` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the `address` column based on `phone` number, here is the xpath. The xpath is dynamic so you don't have to worry thought the column positions change.

```
//table[@id='users-table']//td[.='05680' and position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='Phone']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]/ancestor::tr//td[position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='address']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

If you want to use both `address` and `phone` number in the xpath, use the below.

```
//table[@id='users-table']//td[.='05680' and position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='Phone']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]/ancestor::tr//td[ .= '5 street' and position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='address']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

If you want to click on the button based on `address` and `phone`, use the below xpath (assuming that there is only one button in the row)

```
//table[@id='users-table']//tr[td[.='05680' and position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='Phone']/preceding-sibling::th)+1] and td[ .= '5 street' and position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='address']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]]//button
```

You can define the attribute and value for the button in case.

**edit (add button part)**

```
td[position()=count(//th/button[@id='add-user-button']/../preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

Comment: So you want to find the `add button` based on `address` and `phone' column values?

Comment: Updated the answer with the logic for button. we don't have to rely on the column name for button, as there is only one button in the entire row.